# Converting pyspark.sql.Rowtype data to Json string eliminating values in Azure Databricks NB

Tags: json, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have below pyspark row type data:

```
indv_msg = [Row(cbm_json_output=Row(country_code='USA', date='06-10-2023', date_epoch='1696550400', id='USA-001535-1696550400', interfaceVersion='1.0.0', opmode_car_door=Row(health_category='GREEN', msg_id='1', num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days=0, reason=None, reasonDetail=None), opmode_landing_door=Row(health_category='GREEN', msg_id='1', reason=None, reasonDetail=None), sensor=Row(component_type=None, health_category=None, landing_priority=None, msg_id='1', num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days=None, reason=None, reasonDetail=None), unit_id='001535'))
```

While trying to convert to json string, it is eliminating assign field such as "country_code", "date", ....

```
user_encode_data = json.dumps(indv_msg, indent=2)
```

result :
indv_msg

```
 [
  [
    "USA",
    "06-10-2023",
    "1696550400",
    "USA-001535-1696550400",
    "1.0.0",
    [
      "GREEN",
      "1",
      0,
      null,
      null
    ],
    [
      "GREEN",
      "1",
      null,
      null
    ]
]
```

Expected result:
indv_msg

```
[
  [
    "country_code" : "USA",
    "date" : "06-10-2023",
    "date_epoch": 1696550400",
     ....
     ....
   ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition to @Shubham Sharma you can just call `row.asDict(True)`  with recursive as `True`.

When i tried in my environment even i got the same results.

[image]

So you can use below code block to get json output.

```
indv_msg_dict = [row.asDict(True) for row in indv_msg]

user_encode_data = json.dumps(indv_msg_dict, indent=2)

print(user_encode_data)
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot that there is a parameter.  :-)

Comment: Right as i have nested row type recursive is required , thank you @JayasankerGS

Answer (score 1):

Define a function (`to_dict`) to recursively convert pyspark `Row` type to the corresponding dictionary representation then map this function on each row inside `indv_msg` finally use `json.dumps` to serialize the data

```
def to_dict(row):
    return {
        k: to_dict(v) if isinstance(v, Row) else v
        for k, v in row.asDict().items()
    }

data = json.dumps([to_dict(msg) for msg in indv_msg], indent=4)
```

---

```
print(data)
[
    {
        "cbm_json_output": {
            "country_code": "USA",
            "date": "06-10-2023",
            "date_epoch": "1696550400",
            "id": "USA-001535-1696550400",
            "interfaceVersion": "1.0.0",
            "opmode_car_door": {
                "health_category": "GREEN",
                "msg_id": "1",
                "num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days": 0,
                "reason": null,
                "reasonDetail": null
            },
            "opmode_landing_door": {
                "health_category": "GREEN",
                "msg_id": "1",
                "reason": null,
                "reasonDetail": null
            },
            "sensor": {
                "component_type": null,
                "health_category": null,
                "landing_priority": null,
...
            "unit_id": "001535"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand the issue is about normalization of nested Row type.